# ggplot2 - include one level of a factor in all facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I have some time series data that is facet wrapped by a variable 'treatment'. One of the levels of this 'treatment' factor the a negative control & I want to include it in every facet.

For example using R dataset 'Theoph':

```
data("Theoph")


head(Theoph)

Subject   Wt Dose Time  conc
1       1 79.6 4.02 0.00  0.74
2       1 79.6 4.02 0.25  2.84
3       1 79.6 4.02 0.57  6.57
4       1 79.6 4.02 1.12 10.50
5       1 79.6 4.02 2.02  9.66
6       1 79.6 4.02 3.82  8.58

Theoph$Subject <- factor(Theoph$Subject, levels = unique(Theoph$Subject)) # set factor order

ggplot(Theoph, aes(x=Time, y=conc, colour=Subject)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ Subject)
```

How could I include the data corresponding to Subject '1' (the control) to be included in each facet? (And ideally removing the facet that contains Subject 1's data alone.)

Thank you!

Comment: Seems I cant edit my own question. Should say "And ideally removing the facet that contains Subject 1's data alone."

Comment: You might find these posts helpful [Merge and edit multiple legends when facets and geom_line are plotted separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47327997/merge-and-edit-multiple-legends-when-facets-and-geom-line-are-plotted-separately) or [ggplot2: create a plot using selected facets with part data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48467070/ggplot2-create-a-plot-using-selected-facets-with-part-data) and [ggplot2:: Facetting plot with the same reference plot in all panels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48464000/ggplot2-facetting-plot-with-the-same-reference-plot-in-all-panels)

Comment: You can certainly edit your own question. There's an "edit" link at the bottom left, right below the tags in the blue boxes. `share  edit  close  flag`.

Comment: Thanks for those links Markus, super helpful - I probably wasn't searching with quite the right words & didnt manage to find those

Comment: There's some nice info in this blog post on plotting "background data" on all facets that you might find worth the read: https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/plotting-background-data-for-groups-with-ggplot2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have a certain subject appear in every facet, we need to replicate it's data for every facet. We'll create a new column called `facet`, replicate the Subject 1 data for each other value of Subject, and for Subject != 1, set `facet` equal to `Subject`.

```
every_facet_data = subset(Theoph, Subject == 1)
individual_facet_data = subset(Theoph, Subject != 1)
individual_facet_data$facet = individual_facet_data$Subject

every_facet_data = merge(every_facet_data,
                                                 data.frame(Subject = 1, facet = unique(individual_facet_data$facet)))

plot_data = rbind(every_facet_data, individual_facet_data)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=Time, y=conc, colour=Subject)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ facet)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for but I just couldn't get there! Thanks a million